# Accounting for conditionally correlated predictors in regression model

Tags: multiple-regression

I thought of this question at lunch and don’t know the terminology to search for it perhaps..

Consider Fn X1(mint) + X2(Orange) = Y(flavor)

X1 and X2 are boolean values, capable of values 0 or 1.

Using the following data:

```
| X1  | X2  |  Y  |
| 1   |   0 | 0.5 |
| 0   |   1 | 0.5 |
| 1   |   1 | 0   |
| 0   |   0 | 0   |
```

The flavors orange and mint independently add to the overall flavor, but when present together or neither at all there is no flavor.

I’m sure there is a term for this but with my knowledge of regressions this has me a bit stumped.

Comment: Your notation and terminology are unclear, but it looks like you might be asking about *interactions.*

Comment: Apologies, I added some formatting if that makes it any clearer

Comment: Thanks.  What does "Fn X1" mean?  What exactly is a "true evaluation"?

Comment: The function X1 + X2 = Y? And meaning those conditions are data that the regression is being built on? I don’t know the true terminology I guess in a statistical academic sense. I just dabble in my own, apologies.

Comment: Since your values of Y are not the sums of X1 and X2, I confess I don't understand what you're writing about.  This doesn't seem to be an "academic issue": it's fundamental to communicating your question to the rest of us.

Comment: Apologies, consider X1 and X2 to be boolean values. Possible of 0 and 1. Sorry I'm scraping these from my data trying to simplify it, but it's ending up more convoluted.

Comment: It's usually better to describe the problem and data you actually have rather than trying to simplify it or make it more abstract: you risk losing essential aspects in the translation.

Comment: The core principles of my question are here to the best of my knowledge, only the labels for the variables change and the resulting value of Y.

Comment: @whuber Interaction Term was what I was looking for, thanks for attempting anyway